# No way to get classes from androidx.core (and more..)

Tags: migration, build.gradle, androidx

I'm struggling for hours, unable to import androidx classes such as core and app inside several java files.
I'm using gradle 5.6.1 and 3.2.1 plugin, compiling for SDK v31 with minimum set at v24.
I regularly set SDK and NDK path, I enabled AndroidX and Jetifier in settings, i added, in the gradle.build linked to the module I'm trying to compile, implementation as:

```
implementation androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0 //(this one is working letting me to import the relative class)

implementation androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0 // Not working

implementation androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 // Not working at all

implementation androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0  // Not working at all
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm updating an old library and, even if I successfully built it some months ago, ALREADY updating to androidx, now it seems became impossible for apparently no reason.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by simply upgrading both the Gradle version and the related Gradle Plugin.

It can be obtained by editing the **build.gradle** files, along with the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file

```
// build.gradle (project)
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
[other code here]...}

// build.gradle (module)
android 
{
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'
    [other code here]...
} // this part needs to be updated to, atm v31 is one of the latest ones

// gradle-wrapper.properties
[other code]...
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-bin.zip
```

or (for Android Studio) from menu:

> file->Project Structure->Project (tab)

then choosing Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0 and Gradle Version 6.1.1.

This is not the only working pair, but surely it worked properly.